# Angular router with HashLocationStrategy doesnot read oauth token however it works with PathLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, access-token, router

I am using oAuth with angular2 application. It provides access token in the redirect url. I am able to read the access token using ActivatedRoute when using PathLocationStrategy, however when I change my LocationStrategy to HashLocationStrategy, the ActivatedRoute doesnot read query params from the redirect URL.

I have to use HashLocationStrategy as it supports reload of the page, which in turn doesn't work in case of PathLocationStrategy.

Code to read access_token from redirect url in AppComponent is as follow:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  let token= params.params['access_token'];
  console.log(token); //this return undefined in case of HashLocationStrategy

});
```

Comment: Could you take my a hand with (that question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963162/angular-strange-path-routing-strategy-behavior?noredirect=1#comment78885266_45963162]? I'm using `PathLocationStrategy` but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this in the meantime? If yes, please share!